# Adding Outside Border to a table based on the first row that has merged cells in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel table that looks like this:[image]

And I'm trying to add outside borders based on the first row to get the following output:[image]

I've tried the following, but it does not work. Although I don't get an error, excel would become unresponsive (20 mins) when running the VBA and have to force quit the application. I think it runs into an infinite loop (not sure).

```
Sub shopBorder()
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, borderRange As Range
        Set rng = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Columns.Count).End(xlToRight))
        
        For Each cell In rng
            If cell.MergeArea(1).Address = cell.Address Then
                Set borderRange = .Range(cell.MergeArea, cell.End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlDown))
                AddBorder borderRange
            End If
        Next Cell
   End With
End Sub

Public Function AddBorder(rng As Range)
    rng.BorderAround _
        LineStyle:=xlContinuous, _
        Weight:=xlMedium
End Function
```

Comment: "it does not work" is not very specific. Can you please explain how the code fails to achieve the desired result?

Comment: I don't get an error, but excel would become unresponsive when running the VBA and have to force quit the application. I think it runs into an infinite loop (not sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try the following:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToRight)).Interior.Color = vbRed
```

You will immediately see the problem with setting `rng` as that

Try the following:

```
Sub shopBorder()
        Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, borderRange As Range
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Range("A1").Resize(1, .UsedRange.Columns.Count)
        For Each cell In rng
            i = cell.Address
            j = cell.MergeArea(1).Address
            If cell.MergeArea(1).Address = cell.Address Then
                Set borderRange = .Range(cell.MergeArea, cell.End(xlDown).End(xlDown))
                AddBorder borderRange
            End If
        Next cell
   End With
   
End Sub
```

Comment: It works, but the border does not go down the entire column because there are some blank rows.

Comment: Setting the borderRange to the last row of column Shoes might fix the issue. I can get the correct number of rows ```Set vRng = .Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Rows.Count```. How do I use this in the borderRange variable?

Comment: I got it. ``` Set vRng = .Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))```
```Set borderRange = .Range(cell.MergeArea, cell.Offset(vRng.Rows.Count - 1, 0))```